# Why does the entity object is showing a type cannot be used as a variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

```
try
  { 
     ProductsDB Entities1 = new ProductsDB();
     return cart.DatePurchased + "was successfully inserted";
  }
```

I get errors like
ProductsDBEntitites1 is a type but is used as a variable
and
The type of namespace ProductsDB cannot be found.
ProductsDBEntitites1 is an entity object..
How to solve this?

Comment: you probably want something like `var myInstance = new ProductsDB` or alternativly, if `ProductsDBEntities1` is the name of your base-class: `ProductsDBEntities1 myInstance = new ProductsDB()`. Anyway: what is `cart`?  I further suppose you want to use the freshly created instance of type `ProducstDB` here, don´t you? Your question is pretty unclear, as it´s not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: You should probably add more information about what `ProductsDBEntities1` is, what `ProductsDB` is and what `cart` is.

Comment: `var i = new ProductsDBEntitites1();` Does that compile?

Answer (score 1):

You have forgot to leave a space between your datatype and variable name.

```
ProductsDB Entities1 = new ProductsDB();
```

Comment: still views the error the type or namespace name ProductsDB() could not be found

Comment: Please check if you have used correct namespaces in your file header that has definitions for `ProductsDB` and the class access specifier is public. 
If you still get the problem, try reopening the solution/ clean, rebuild the project to refresh the references.

Answer (score -3):

Variable missing + using clause missing:

```
use mynamespace;  // Open the file where ProductsDB is defined, copy the namespace and paste it here
try
  {
     ProductsDBEntities1 cart = new ProductsDB();
     return cart.DatePurchased + "was successfully inserted";
  }
```

Comment: Instead of guessing what OP **may** have mentioned, we should ask for more information, shouldn´t we? Even thouhgh that´s what I supposed also.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Guessing what? OP has created a DB context in a 2 lines try clause. You don't have to be a medium to _guess_ that his intent is to use it. First line: DB context created but not assigned. Second and last line, variable not declared used. If cart is not a ProductDB(), there are many more problems than an undeclared variable and a missing namespace. Let him/her try what I have written and come back.

Comment: The problem is exactly, that OPs problem *might* be somwething completely different (as you´ve indicated in the last sentence in your comment) which makes your answer completely useless o both OP **and** the community. Of course chances are high that you guessed write about OPs problem.